# Jmeter - url from command line

Tags: jmeter

I have been trying to pass the url for a web page from the command line to do performance testing using Jmeter.

I had set up the user defined variables like

```
  NumberOfUsers         ${__P(NumberOfUsers,2)}
  HowManyTimesToRun     ${__P(HowManyTimesToRun,2)}
  RampUpTime                ${__P(RampUpTime, 10)}
  Host                  ${__P(Host)}
```

I tried using the Jmeter command as

```
 ./jmeter.sh -n  -t Performance.jmx -l old88.jtl -JNumberOfUsers=5 -JRampUpTime=10JHowManyTimesToRun=2 -JHost=www.google.com
```

It seems to take all the values correctly except the host name. Is there a way to pass the url from command line. I use this property in HTTP request Defaults.

Comment: During the test, is ${NumberOfUsers} resolved as 5 or 2? You have provided defaults for all except Host, i wonder if it is coincedence that this value is not working... Can you use the properties directly in the samples rather than variables. Variables have limited scope, so if you defined them in a threadgroup, they won't be available to a different threadgroup. Where did you place the User Defined Variables element?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any issues here - except a space ' '  and '-' are missing for 'HowManyTimesToRun' property. Maybe it s a typo!!

```
./jmeter.sh -n  -t Performance.jmx -l old88.jtl -JNumberOfUsers=5 -JRampUpTime=10 -JHowManyTimesToRun=2 -JHost=www.google.com
```

Comment: Actually I had copy pasted it wrong. I ran the command line in the way you have mentioned